# How to send Int32 input to database through SqlDataSource stored procedure parameter in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, webforms

Basically,  I have a Gridview. I am getting the text value of a specific cell and putting in an asp label.

Now I want to use that label's text as input for a stored procedure on an SqlDatasource like so

```
       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="AddressContactSource"
          runat="server"
          ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UACOrdersConnectionString %>"
          SelectCommand="GetAddressContact" 
          SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                  <SelectParameters>
                      <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Silver"
                          Name="@AccountID"
                          PropertyName="Text"
                          Type="Int32" DefaultValue="2624" />

                  </SelectParameters>
              </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The problem is this doesn't work because AccountID (the input parameter for stored proceedure) is an int32 and the Label's text is a string so it does not show any results in the Details view that is bound to the SqlDatasource.

Now I have a method for selected index changed in the codebehind for the gridview that puts the cell.

```
  protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string temp = GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[5].Text;
        Silver.Text = temp;
        int temp2 = Convert.ToInt32(temp, 10);
        Parameter p = new Parameter();
        p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        p.Type = TypeCode.Int32;
        p.Name = "@AccountID";
        AddressContactSource.SelectParameters.Add(p);
        AddressContact.DataBind();
        updatepanel1.Update();
    }
```

My code compiles and doesn't throw any exceptions in debug either. I know this is close, but Parameter doesn't have a constructor that takes an int. 
So I can't add it. So, what do I do?

Comment: I don't really know which namespace Parameter class belongs but if it is the same as the SqlParameter. You can just do p.Value = someInt;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to have parameter name start with `@` (you need it only if stored procedure input parameter starts from `@@`).

Also I believe you don't need to add parameter in `SelectedIndexChanged` handler, as soon as you updated label text and called `DataBind` control parameter should automatically get the new value.